# Co-browsing support: initiated by customer or service rep?

Tags: usability, security, workflow, chat

We are currently putting together a co-browse feature for customers using web chat on our website, and the software that was purchased allows the customer to initiate a co-browse session (take control of the pointer etc.) and then waits for the service rep to connect.

My question is should the co-browse feature be initiated by the service rep's end? or continue to allow users to activate the feature from the chat UI, screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Did you do user testing on whether or not to have this function? Your button says "Share screen" but you're actually taking control of their computer? You guys should test real users on this "feature" before anything else.

Comment: sadly not, this was an ask by the company with no prior user testing or real rationale so we are retrofitting the solution.

Comment: You should get some real user reactions and feedback on it. Get a couple videos of users new to "screen sharing" discovering this button, figuring out what it is, using it, and reacting to what it does. Good reactions on video is all you need to get, not formal testing and documentation. Also, getting access to a user's computer and private files is a huge liability. Does legal know about it? You'll need a higher level of agent on your end to take control of user's computers as opposed to just answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the end user who is requesting the support's role to accept that they share what's on their screen.

Sure I understand that the support person would find it easier if they always could share the screen.

But I wouldn't be comfortable if someone out of the blue requested screen sharing with me.

You should always try to have a dialog with your customer and to me "screen sharing" should be the last option; like requesting someone coming home to you and help you out.

If you can't help the customer out via chat; then the service-rep might suggest to the customer that he or she shares screen.

Helping someone is all about making the customer feel great about themselves and the end result.

Some people might be offended if you "jump the gun" and request screen share without prior question.

So keep that in mind!